# Как вывести значение текущей и будущей даты в проценте? PHP

Tags: php, дата

Имеется следующие данные:
Будущая дата: 10.12.2020
Текущая дата: 10.11.2020
Хотел бы посредством PHP вычислить текущий процент от текущей даты до будущей даты
Каждый день когда текущая дата всё ближе подходит к будущей даты то происходит уменьшения процента (на одно дневное значение), будущая дата 100 (%)

Comment: Тогда у вас должна быть начальная дата - это 0%, конечная дата - 100% ну и текущая это [текущая дата]/([конечная дата] - [начальная дата])*100 я правильно понял?

Comment: @Tunker Да совершенно верно, текущая 0, конечная 100 (без символа процента)

Comment: Немного не так, должно быть 3 даты, к примеру начальная 16.10.2020 конечная 16.12.2020 а текущая 16.11.2020 - это будет 50% а если только 2 даты текущая и конечная то всегда будет 100%

Comment: @Tunker по формуле как должно быть чтоб в php вписал код

Comment: https://expange.ru/e/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8_(PHP)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы посчитать % от даты, их надо 3: начальная, конечная и текущая

```
$date_begin = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i:s', '16.10.2020 00:00:00')->getTimestamp();
$date_end = DateTime::createFromFormat('d.m.Y H:i:s', '16.12.2020 00:00:00')->getTimestamp();
$date_current = strtotime("now");
$percent=round(($date_current-$date_begin)/($date_end-$date_begin)*100,1);
```

Это вернет % текущей даты в промежутке от начальной - 0% до конечной 100% (округляя до 1 знака после запятой)

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
// Первая дата
$d1 = '2020-11-10 00:01:00';

// Вторая дата
$d2 = '2020-12-10 23:59:59';

// timestamp первой даты
$d1_ts = strtotime($d1);

// timestamp второй даты
$d2_ts = strtotime($d2);

// Количество секунд
// Функция abs нужна, чтобы не проверять какая из двух дат больше
$seconds = abs($d1_ts - $d2_ts);

// Количество дней нужно округлить в меньшую сторону,
// чтобы узнать точное количество прошедших дней
// 86400 - количество секунд в 1 дней (60 * 60 * 24)
$days = floor($seconds / 86400);
echo "Всего дней:";
echo $days;//3
echo "<br>";

$today = date("Y-m-d H:i:s"); 




$d1_today = strtotime($today);


$seconds1 = abs($d1_today - $d2_ts);

$days1 = floor($seconds1 / 86400);


$pocent=($days1*100)/$days;

Echo "Осталось дней в процентах:";
print_r($pocent."%");

?>
```

Comment: Вы переборщили с проверками дат, какая из них больше. Если больше 2 дата и текущая будет совпадать с ней, то будет 0%  а должно показать 100%, если так заморачиваться, тода уж лучше сделать проверку и если первая дата меньше чем вторая, менять их местами, тогда первая дата - всегда будет конечной, вторая начальной. Ну и тогда добавить проверку на равенство дат (начальной и конечной) если они равны то выдавать ошибку, иначе деление на 0.